# How to update xml Tags using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

I am able to read xml file using jquery,xml and html

But i need to change a tag value in xml with jquery.

I need to do this task in offline using client side script only

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple.

If you use for example `your_tag.attr('attribute_name')` to read from xml node, you simply do `your_tag.attr('attribute_name',value)` to write to that value. (This is for tag attribute value)

If you want to change all your tag's children (not it's attributes but all "inside" your tag) just write `your_tag.html('your_value')`